# Задание с массивом структур

Tags: c

Задание: 
Объявить структуру, содержащую строки, соответствующие имени и фамилии человека. Создать массив из 10 таких структур, инициализировать их именами и фамилиями любых известных людей. Напечатать список людей, чье имя совпадает с именем, которое ввел пользователь.

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
int i;
struct scientist
{
char name[20];
char surname[20];
};
struct scientist a = {"",""};
struct scientist physic[] = {   {"джеймс","максвелл"},
                                {"томас","юнг"},
                                {"генри","кавендиш"},
                                {"джон","флеминг"},
                                {"исаак","ньютон"},
                                {"иоганн","бернулли"},
                                {"генри","джозеф"},
                                {"джеймс","уотсон"},
                                {"томас","эдисон"},
                                {"иоганн","кеплер"} };
printf ("Введите имя: ");
scanf("%s",&a.name);
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if (strcmp(a.name,physic[i].name)==0)
        printf("%s",physic[i]);
}
}
```

Компилируется, запускается, но, когда ввожу имя выходит ошибка "прекращена работа a.exe...". Компилирую в mingw. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вообще, конечно, надо в отладчике смотреть... Ошибка при любом вводе или при вводе имени из структуры? Кстати,  printf("%s",physic[i]); будет работать совсем не так как вы ожидаете.

Comment: Вообще-то надо написать `scanf("%s", a.name);` и `printf("%s\n",physic[i].name);`, но и так должна работать (возможно Вы не тот код сюда скопипастили...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По крайней мере исправьте данное предложение

```
scanf("%20s",a.name);
       ^^^^  ^^^^^^
```

И в данном предложении напишите

```
if (strcmp(a.name,physic[i].name)==0)
    printf("%s %s\n",physic[i].name, physic[i].surname);
```

Предложение цикла правильнее будет написать

```
size_t i;

//...

for( i = 0; i < sizeof( physic ) / sizeof( *physic ); i++ )
```

И функция main без аргументов в C должна быть объявлена как

```
int main( void )
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: с первым - понятно, я просто экспериментировал и забыл исправить, второе - в этом вся причина была.
а остальное - понятно в принципе, но по программе универа не положено еще. так что, думаю, сойдет так, раз работает.

Спасибо за ответы!